# How do I show the SVN revision number in git log?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm customizing my git log to be all in 1 line. Specifically, I added the following alias:

```
lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset - %C(yellow)%an%Creset - %s %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

So, when I run `git lg`, I see the following:

```
* 41a49ad - zain - commit 1 message here (3 hours ago)
* 6087812 - zain - commit 2 message here (5 hours ago)
* 74842dd - zain - commit 3 message here (6 hours ago)
```

However, I want to add the SVN revision number in there too, so it looks something like:

```
* 41a49ad - r1593 - zain - commit 1 message here (3 hours ago)
```

The normal `git log` shows you the SVN revision number, so I'm sure this must be possible. How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say that "the normal `git log` shows you the SVN revision number", I guess you mean that you are dealing with a repository handled by `git svn`, which by default adds a line like this at the end of the synchronized commits:

```
git-svn-id: svn://path/to/repository@###### <domain>
```

Now, as far as git is concerned, this is just random text, so I doubt that you can find a `%` accessor to read the `######` revision number from there.

At this point your best option would be to just parse the output of plain `git log` by yourself. Here's a crude starting point:

```
git log -z | tr '\n\0' ' \n' | sed 's/\(commit \S*\) .*git-svn-id: svn:[^@]*@\([0-9]*\) .*/\1 r\2/'
```

Comment: VonC's solution is much simpler

Answer (score 31):

Consider the command [`git svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)

- it has a similar log function than [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log): `git svn log`
- it has the [`find-rev`](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=117783576219600&w=2) option (to retrieve the SVN revision from a SHA1 key) (introduced in [git 1.6.0](https://lkml.org/lkml/2008/8/17/174))

I am not sure of you can combine those two options in one command line though.
A script (a bit like [this one](http://dev.haiku-os.org/ticket/2860) which is not exactly what you want but still can give some idea) might be in order.

---

[sdaau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277826/sdaau) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870506/how-do-i-show-the-svn-revision-number-in-git-log/2870979#comment38600887_2870979):

> An example of this:

```
git svn find-rev $(git log --max-count 1 --pretty=format:%H)
```

---

[Adversus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/678022/adversus) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870506/how-do-i-show-the-svn-revision-number-in-git-log/2870979?noredirect=1#comment102717123_2870979):

> Note that `find-rev` searches in the current branch, so if you're in `master` and `rxyz` happened in a branch, `find-rev` will not find it.
>   You can give `-B` (before) or `-A` (after) options for a wider search, see [`git svn find-rev` man page section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-emfind-revem).

Comment: An example of this: `git svn find-rev $(git log --max-count 1 --pretty=format:%H)`

Comment: @sdaau Thank you. I have included your example in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Those links to the mailing lists are broken. Could you replace them with a more appropriate link? E.g. the web archive http://web.archive.org/web/20070615164322/http://lists-archives.org/git/423371-git-svn-add-find-rev-command.html

Comment: @RobW no need for web.archive.org ;) I have restored the links.

Comment: How do you add the result of this command to a git log ? I have an alias `lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit`, how can I insert the SVN revision ?

Comment: @thomasb 6 years later, not too sure: try and ask a new question for all to see.

Comment: Note that `find-rev` searches in the current branch, so if you're in master and rxyz happened in a branch `find-rev` will not find it. You can give `-B` or `-A` options for a wider search, see [find-rev](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-emfind-revem)

Comment: @Adversus Thank you (for commenting on this 9-years old question). I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC thanks for the 9 years old answer ;) Just trying to help other poor souls stuck in the git-svn vcs limbo.

Answer (score 15):

Run:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

which gives you git commit hash.

Then use that commit hash to run:

```
git svn find-rev <commit_hash>
```

Which gives you svn revision.

Comment: I like this answer best, because it seems most direct. Here's my take on a one-line version: ```echo "r$(git svn find-rev $(git rev-parse HEAD))"```. This works as an alias of course: ```rev = !echo "r$(git svn find-rev $(git rev-parse HEAD))"```

Comment: I like this answer best, because it seems most direct. Here's my take on a one-line version: ```echo "r$(git svn find-rev $(git rev-parse HEAD))"```. This works as an alias of course: ```svnrev = !echo "r$(git svn find-rev $(git rev-parse HEAD))"```. This also makes it so you can mimic svn export even better ```export = !git archive --format zip --output /tmp/$(git svnrev) master```

Comment: `git svn find-rev` also works the other way round, just specify the SVN revision number prefixed with an r: `git svn find-rev r63919`.

Comment: Maybe this wasn't true when you submitted the answer (or I have special git/svn version), but for me it also works to simply write `git svn find-rev HEAD`.

Comment: Actually the right command seems to be `git svn find-rev master` as you could be currently in another branch and svn in syncronized with 'master' branch if I'm not wrong

Comment: This only works if you don't have any local commits you haven't pushed to SVN. Otherwise it will come back blank!

Answer (score 8):

Ended up with something like this:

```
git svn log --oneline -1 | cut -d '|' -f1
```

That gives the last revision from that repo (you can tweak `git svn log` parameters for showing another revision, but keep `--oneline` and `-1`), but with a trailing whitespace (something like `"r9441 "`) that I think should be easy to strip out.

Hope it helps...

Comment: That does not work, this works: `git svn log --oneline --limit=1`.