# Built-in command to checkout a specific Subversion revision which doesn't use the 'rNNNNN' format from a Git mirror?

Tags: git, svn, reference, commit, git-checkout

I am compiling from a local Git mirror of a Subversion repository and I need to checkout out particular commits from the Subversion revision number from the mirror.

The `git log` displays something like this: and by locating the `git-svn-id: xxxx  xxxx@revision-number` line it should be possible to locate the right reference and check it out. But there are lots of revisions and it is bound to get awkward if I want to go way back in time. Is there a built-in to accomplish this?

```
commit xxxx-yyyy-fb12992fabd6a1165697ded73851d26993
Author: mattias <mattias@4005530d-fff6-0310-9dd1-cebe43e6787f>
Date:   Fri Mar 6 16:25:06 2015 +0000

    fpcunit: guitestrunner: scroll to first error after run, patch from Graeme, issue 27613

    git-svn-id: http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/lazarus/trunk@48152 4005530d-fff6-0310-9dd1-cebe43e6787f
```

UPDATE: relating to possible duplicate.
`git svn find-rev` referenced in [Checkout the git commit corresponding to a certain revision from the old SVN repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599707/checkout-the-git-commit-corresponding-to-a-certain-revision-from-the-old-svn-rep?lq=1) applies to repositories that use the `rN`style of revision number, and that is not the case for all SVN repositories, and this one as well. Using it results in the error messages similar to the one below.

```
fatal: Not a valid object name 95059
cat-file commit 95059: command returned error: 128
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checkout the git commit corresponding to a certain revision from the old SVN repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599707/checkout-the-git-commit-corresponding-to-a-certain-revision-from-the-old-svn-rep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the answer from [How do I show the SVN revision number in git log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870506/how-do-i-show-the-svn-revision-number-in-git-log), my solution is to `grep` for the revision id an `cut` out the Git commit hash.

```
git log -z | tr '\n\0' ' \n' | sed 's/\(commit \S*\) .*git-svn-id: \  
svn:[^@]*@\([0-9]*\) .*/\1 r\2/' | grep trunk@NNNNN | cut -d " " -f 2
```

The `trunk` minimizes the chance of matching the NNNNN string if it appears in another commit message in which is not the commit id. The hash can be shortened by piping the output through another `cut -b 1-8`

Answer (score 1):

If your local repository is being managed with `git svn`, then you can use [`git svn find-rev`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

```
   find-rev
       When given an SVN revision number of the form rN, returns the
       corresponding Git commit hash (this can optionally be followed by a
       tree-ish to specify which branch should be searched). When given a
       tree-ish, returns the corresponding SVN revision number.
```

For example:

```
git svn find-rev r48152
```

Comment: `git svn find-rev` applies to repositories that use the `rN`revision no, and that it not the case for all SVN repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you still have an svn-remote branch on your local Git mirror. 
With this it should be very simple. Try this.

```
git svn fetch <svn-remote>
git checkout remotes/<Remote Name>
git svn log --show-commit --oneline
```

Refer my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39653616/4328594).