# Append command result to git log pretty format

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a bunch of pretty `git log` aliases using pretty-format, like such:

```
lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

which gives me this:

```
* cb847da - (HEAD -> master, origin/trunk) foo (4 hours ago) <thomasb>
* 2117663 - bar (8 hours ago) <thomasb>
```

I'm actually using git-svn, and I have a different command to list the SVN revisions:

```
slg = svn log --oneline --show-commit
```

I want to insert the SVN revision inside my `git lg` output. I have found [how to get the SVN revision of a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2870979/6776) (`git svn find-rev $(git log --max-count 1 --pretty=format:%H)`), but I can't find how to insert a command result inside a pretty-format, so I would get something like this for instance:

```
* cb847da - r1234 - (HEAD -> master, origin/trunk) foo (4 hours ago) <thomasb>
* 2117663 - r1233 - bar (8 hours ago) <thomasb>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slow but works as you want it:

```
git config alias.lgs '!git log --graph --pretty=format:'\''%Cred%h%Creset - %C(bold red)-%H-%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset'\'' --abbrev-commit | while IFS=- read -r prefix color revision rest; do echo "$prefix-$color$(git svn find-rev "$revision")$rest"; done'
```

of if you prefer to edit the config files directly:

```
lgs = "!git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset - %C(bold red)-%H-%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit | while IFS=- read -rprefix color revision rest; do echo \"$prefix-$color$(git svn find-rev \"$revision\")$rest\"; done"
```

Comment: Probably great on Unix but doesn't work on Windows :(

Comment: If you use the Git Bash or Cygwin, it should work fine on Windows. Where does it not work on Windows?

Comment: True ; I do not use either git bash or cygwin. The git binaries are added to the path and I use plain old powershell.

Comment: Then do the same with Powershell magic. I'm not too familiar with PS. What the alias is, is just adding the full hash in and then replace in the output lines the hash by the result of `git svn find-rev <hash>`.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have created a Powershell alias ([source](https://gist.github.com/cosmo0/ffa9617596793514ce68f8e33646af2f)) to get a message (to copy/paste in bugtracker messages) but it's pretty long and complicated for not much:

```
function Get-GitSvnMessage (
  $rev
) {
  if ($rev -eq $null -or $rev -eq "") {
    $rev = "HEAD"
  }

  # get svn revision
  $svn = (git svn find-rev $rev)

  # get git message
  $msg = (git show -s --format=%B $rev | ? { $_ -notmatch "^git-svn-id:" -and $_.Trim() -ne "" })

  # get changed files
  $files = (git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r $rev)

  Write-Output "SVN revision $svn"
  Write-Output $msg
  Write-Output ""
  Write-Output $files
}
```